# Assigning data to class variables in c#

Tags: c#, class, object

I have two classes as below-

```
public class dayInOutLog
{
   public string status{ get; set;}
   public int inTime{ get; set;}
   public int outTime{ get; set;}
}
public class Emp_dayInOutLog
{
    public string id{ get; set;}
    public List<dayInOutLog>  listOf_inOut { get; set;} 
}
```

Now I need to set values for object of Emp_dayInOutLog class and I am trying as below but I am not able to access status,inTime,outTime of listOf_inOut.

```
Emp_dayInOutLog obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog ();

    obj.Add (new Emp_dayInOutLog {id = "1",listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog> {   status = "Absent",inTime = 585, outTime = 690}          });
```

Where I am wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do only :

```
 Emp_dayInOutLog obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog()
            {
                id = "1",
                listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog> {
                new dayInOutLog(){
                   status = "Absent",
                   inTime = 585,
                   outTime = 690
                }
            }
            };
```

And you can access your status for example doing :

```
obj.listOf_inOut.ElementAt(0).status
```

The Add() method doesn't exist in the context of `Emp_dayInOutLog`, you **can't use it** on `obj`. 
But you could use on its list by doing :

```
obj.listOf_InOut.Add(New dayInOutLog () {...})
```

Answer (score 2):

Correction: you have to add an instance of type `dayInOutLog` inside the list, like:

```
Emp_dayInOutLog obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog {
            id = "1",
            listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog> {
              new dayInOutLog()    <-----------------
              {
                status = "Absent",
                inTime = 585,
                outTime = 690
              }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

you Need to create not only a new list but also a new `dayInOutLog` object

```
obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog() {
            id = "1",
            listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog> {
                 new dayInOutLog(){
                    status = "Absent",
                    inTime = 585,
                    outTime = 690
                 }
            }
        });
```

if you would create it step by step your code will become more readable
and you would find such Errors more easily
Also if you would give the classes a constructor you could just pass the values at the point of creation:

```
class dayInOutLog
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int inTime { get; set; }
    public int outTime { get; set; }

    public dayInOutLog(string st, int t_1, int t_2)
    {
        this.status = st;
        this.inTime = t_1;
        this.outTime = t_2;
    }
}

public class Emp_dayInOutLog
{
    public string id{ get; set;}
    public List<dayInOutLog>  listOf_inOut { get; set;}

    public Emp_dayInOutLog(string _id)
    {
        this.id = _id;
        this.listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog>();
    }
}
```

And your creation of these object could look like this:

```
Emp_dayInOutLog obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog("1");

obj.listOf_inOut.Add(new dayInOutLog("Absent", 585, 690));
```

Answer (score 1):

listOf_inOut doesn't have status, inTime and outTime properties directly. It's a list of dayInOutLog records and *those* have these properties.

Your code to add a new log entry should read:

```
var log = new Emp_dayInOutLog {
            id = "1",
            listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog>
            {
                new dayInOutLog
                {
                    status = "Absent",
                    inTime = 585,
                    outTime = 690
                }
            }
        });
```

Then you can access this by using any list control loop or indices.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create dayInOutLog and then add it to list:

```
var obj = new Emp_dayInOutLog() {
            id = "1",
            listOf_inOut = new List<dayInOutLog> {
                new dayInOutLog(){
                   status = "Absent",
                   inTime = 585,
                   outTime = 690
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: Add() doent exist in this context.

Comment: My mistake, I copy it and just overlooked, that he didn't use `List<Emp_dayInOutLog>`, thanks for notice. Corrected.